# Перевести с QPILE ( интерпретируемый командный язык "якобы" основан на VBScript) на JScript

Tags: javascript

Вот такая проблема. 
Есть код реализующий паузу текущего исполнения, написанный на QPILE (терминал QUIK ) и этот код  успешно работает (делает паузу на заданный период времени):

```
    ' функция реализации временной паузы

    PST = GET_DATETIME()
    FIRST_SYS_TIME = 0+GET_VALUE(PST, "HOUR")*3600000 + GET_VALUE(PST, 
    "MIN")*60000 + GET_VALUE(PST, "SEC")*1000 + GET_VALUE(PST, "MILLISEC")

    FOR PST_FLAG FROM 0 TO 1
    PST = GET_DATETIME()
    SECOND_SYS_TIME = 0+GET_VALUE(PST, "HOUR")*3600000 + GET_VALUE(PST, 
    "MIN")*60000 + GET_VALUE(PST, "SEC")*1000 + GET_VALUE(PST, "MILLISEC")
     DIFF_TIME=(SECOND_SYS_TIME-FIRST_SYS_TIME)
    IF DIFF_TIME<= PAUSE_TIME*1000
    PST_FLAG = -1

    END IF
    END FOR
```

Есть еще вторая (Первая) программа AmiBroker (скриптовый Язык AFL, встроенный в  программу).  Поддержка AFL COM  позволяет вызывать функции, определенные в скриптовой части JScript, непосредственно из AFL без использования переменных для   передачи данных и извлечения данных из скрипта.
Это приамбула . Суть вопроса - как код отраженный выше перенести (изложить ) на  JScript... 
По сути нужна пауза (остановка для ВСЕХ и ВСЕГО 3-5 сек. ) на заданный период  времени с момента возникновения события, для реализации ранее отложенных или уже  заявленных процедур...).
 Как то так... Надеюсь внятно изложил...обращение на Ами форум уже почти месяц без  акцепта...

Comment: с какой именно частью кода возникла проблема с переносом? Ты понимаешь как работает приведенный код?

Comment: Как работает код - понимаю. Мне так кажется.

Comment: Как работает код - понимаю. Мне так кажется... ) Фиксируем время  начала паузы FIRST_SYS_TIME ,  далее в цикле читаем  текущее время SECOND_SYS_TIME, и пока  SECOND_SYS_TIME <=  FIRST_SYS_TIME+ PAUSE_TIME*1000  цикл  имеет флаг  PST_FLAG = -1  и вращается (зациклен)   "внутри себя" ... Держит паузу , останавливая  итерацию  всего кода  в этом месте...  Вот этот момент - цикл FOR  зациклен внутри себя  - и не получается....

Comment: _FLAG = 0;
PAUSE_TIME = 8;

StaticVarSet( "FIRST_Time", Now( format = 4 ) );

FOR ( i = 0 ; _FLAG < 0; i++ )
{
FIRST_Time = Nz(StaticVarGet( "FIRST_Time" ));
SECOND_TIME = Now(format = 4);

if( SECOND_TIME <= FIRST_Time + PAUSE_TIME ) _FLAG = -1;

printf("_FLAG = "+ NumToStr(_FLAG ,1.0)+"\n") ;

}

Comment: Это мой вариант на  Язык AFL (якобы основан на С++).  Не работает ...

Comment: как минимум потому, что ты установил флаг в 0, и сразу проверяешь его что он <0, из-за этого в цикл ни разу не заходит